# How to apply Static Data Masking With Replication of Database

Tags: sql-server, replication, azure-sql-database, data-masking

We used to have multiple environments for applications such as Production, Staging, UAT, Dev, and Sandbox. It is a regular task for the DBA to refresh the lower (staging, test, UAT etc.) environments with a backup of the production database backup. Sometimes we need to share the database backup with the external vendors as well.

How to Apply Static Data Masking With Replication of Databases , i.e for every change the replication database to to apply mask and save masked records in staging, test, UAT etc.

Is there any tools or process or methods available ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'Replication of Databases'? Do you mean transactional replication?

Comment: Yes @SqlWorldWide

Answer (score 2):

These are out of the box features of SQL Server so you'll essentially need to follow the Microsoft Books Online and other resources on setting them up. **Replication** has a lot of small steps and basic prerequisites but it's essentially a wizard, so it's rather *simple* if you just follow the documentation carefully.

Here's some helpful references for setting up **Replication**:

1. [Microsoft Books Online - SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [Quick walkthrough on setting up Replication](https://hevodata.com/learn/sql-server-replication/)
3. [More in depth walkthrough for setting up Replication](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-replication-basic-setup-and-configuration/)

And here's some good resources on implementing **Static Data Masking**:

1. [Microsoft Books Online - Static Data Masking for Azure SQL Database and SQL Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/static-data-masking-preview/)
2. [SQL Server Static Data Masking Example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5939/sql-server-static-data-masking-example/)
3. [Static Data Masking in SSMS 18](https://www.sqlshack.com/static-data-masking-in-ssms-18/)

Please note that **Static Data Masking** is only available in SQL Server 2019 (or equivalent Azure SQL Database version). So if you're on an older version of SQL Server, the alternative option available is called [**Dynamic Data Masking**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @JD Is Static Data Masking For Azure SQL Database And SQL Server available , we are tried same version as you mentions but we did not see any options in SSMS

Comment: @Ramakrishna.p I think it's available, in a somewhat beta version, but you need to have the latest version of **SSMS** installed for the option to show up in the UI.

Comment: @JD Do we need enable any Settings in SSMS , we installed as per your shared article , but we could not see options in tasks.

Comment: @Ramakrishna.p I'll have to take a look when I get off work later. I don't believe you need to enable anything special, but I'm not positive. You're definitely using SQL Server 2019?

Comment: SSMS Static Data Masking was removed.  One option is to apply changes with replication using custom stored procedure that masks data (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-articles-specify-how-changes-are-propagated?view=sql-server-ver15) or configure Dynamic Data Masking and write an ETL job that reads the masked values.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Hi David, any news regarding static data masking? I need to anonymize the data if I want to use the data in a test environment because of GDPR. What other suggestions do you have other than the two option you mention?